# Who works professionally on reformulation of QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, soft-question, renormalization

P. Dirac was worried with the infinities and their discarding in QED. He wanted us to reformulate the theory in order to eliminate infinities and renormalizations from the very beginning. Is there anybody who works professionally on this subject? I mean, who earns his salary for that. I know several amateurs but no one professional.

Comment: Well, this is a controversial question but it managed to live peacefully -- thus I reopen it to prevent escalation. @Close-voters, please use downvotes to criticize questions.

Comment: @mbq This is peaceful only when the moderator is fast enough to delete all offensive comments. It also had 5 votes to close and 13 down votes, which must be some sort of a record. It is not formulated as an answerable question and Vladimir is dismissive of any attempt to explain to him the very well known physics  involved. If you want "controversy" and discussion of fringe theories, suit yourself. I will not be willing to be associated with this kind of stuff, and i predict the same applies to any self-respecting professional.

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to look for the following book, [Finite Quantum Electrodynamics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387510583): this is not something "fringe" nor some "crackpot" off-shoot.

The name of the game is [Causal Perturbation Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_perturbation_theory), and was pioneered by [Epstein, Glaser: "The role of locality in perturbation theory"](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/item?id=AIHPA_1973__19_3_211_0).

As far as i understand your question (in the context of your comments, etc), this answer should suffice. However, maybe it'd be a good idea to take a look at what's known as [Local Quantum Physics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540610499): i think this can give you a broader view.

PS: Another route that seems worth pursuing is that of [Vertex Operator Algebra (VOAs)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_operator_algebra) (sometimes known just as 'Borcherds Algebra'). Note that these "infinities problems" appear in QFT because, ultimately, we're multiplying distributions (in the sense of generalized functions — in fact, operator-valued distributions) at the same point, which is not an allowed operation mathematically speaking. Thus, the way out is to do what people have suggested above and follow Ken Wilson's approach of "point-splitting": this is just the physicist's version of the idea behind VOAs. The bottom line is that *every* QFT is valid *only* on some energy scale, so when you cross such line, you're bound to get meaningless results (think of it as the sites of your lattice — defined by this energy scale — merging: completely distinct points gradually become the same). In this fashion, you can take the following path: *define* your QFT via a certain VOA that *explicitly* sets your energy scale in its [Operator product expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_product_expansion) — which is nothing but the 'multiplication rule' of the VOA you have at hands. In principle, this is mathematically rigorous, although **very** difficult. In any case, this also answers your question.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have both editions of the Scharf's book. It is the same as the others - the same equations, the same S-matrix but a different starting point. You know, QED equations with the initial data contain everything in a causal way. You have just to make calculations. Namely these calculations contain infinities. So the conclusion should be - we have a bad theory. Scharf's trick consists in saying that the delta-function arguments in the product $[\delta (x-x_1)]^2$ do not coincide. It is funny. I did not find any difference between subtraction and Scharf's way to put the integral to zero.

Comment: I agree that any theory is incomplete because it does not include possibly undiscovered yet heavy particles or excitations. But it does not mean that any theory should be singular at short distances. These "points" are quite distant!

Comment: Dear Daniel, I am not interested in a "mathematically rigorous" way of working with the standard QFT. I am interested in a physical reformulation.

Comment: Regarding your first comment above, i *explicitly* addressed it in my "PS" — in fact, this was the *raison d'être* for my editing my original answer in order to add the "PS". So, i simply don't understand what you meant. Further, "these points" are not "quite distant" as you seem to think: they are $1/\Lambda$ from each other, where $\Lambda$ is the energy scale of your problem: the more energy, the less apart they are.

Comment: I have spoken of the following "points" or statements: 1) Any theory is incomplete with respect to the nature because it does not include highly excited states properly (we do no know them yet); 2) Any theory should be "singular at short distances" because of such incompleteness. These two statements ("points") are not the same! I believe we can advance phenomenological constructions (theories) free of infinities from the very beginning and flexible enough to incorporate possible higher excitations. Constructing such theories is a physical reformulation rather than VOA of the standard theory.

Comment: @Vladimir: both of your points above — as expressed — have to do with the same question, the so-called *UV-completeness* of the theory. This, in turn, is related to Renormalization, VOAs, and so on.

Comment: @Daniel: yes, they often say so - "UV completeness" as if it were the true problem and the true "explanation" of infinities. I would like to find people who think differently. I think our theories are imperfect in another aspect, namely - in correctly describing interactions. Some part of interaction cannot be considered perturbatively and should be taken into account exactly. It is another initial approximation and another physics implemented in equations. Maybe you know somebody who is trying to proceed from this understanding?

Comment: @Vladimir: I know people trying a few different things, but some (if not most) of them requires much more 'hardcore' math — which you have already dismissed above. In any case, the Clay Institute is offering a big prize for whomever can pull this off…

Comment: @Daniel: I do not dismiss any math, just on the contrary. For example, I consider the integral of delta-function squared to be infinity or a large positive number anyway. I simply do not accept manipulating with the calculation results. Can you give me some names, please? Via e-mail. Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel: speaking of products of distributions, normally such infinities are regularized artificially with some regulators. Now, imagine another initial approximation for an electron where electron is coupled permanently to something. Such a coupling will give a natural regulator (form-factor) because of smearing the electron position in a bound state. So another initial approximation for an electron may resolve the problem. That is why I speak of partially taking into account the always present interaction "electron-oscillators". This is an example of  reformulation.

Comment: @Vladimir: regarding your comments about regulators… i think there's something missing, for the VOA (or OPE) uniquely determines the *interactions* of the theory: this algebraic structure encodes the interactions. What you described above is just a rudimentary way of saying the same thing.

Comment: @Daniel: No, if you take into account a part of existing interactions, then the perturbative reminder will be different from what you got used to. The vertex will be different - non singular, and some part of interaction will be present in the initial approximation. Currently it is not the case.

Comment: If this is going to go on further, it's probably better handled in the chat room.

Comment: @David Zaslavski: I am still waiting for names but they prefer teaching and blaming me.

Comment: It's very frustrating to sit down and take the time to write a meaningful and relevant answer (including refs to original work), just to get downvoted without a single comment explaining the reasons of such action. Where i come from, this has a very clear name: trolling. Maybe this is the tip-of-the-iceberg of having a question-&-answer site for topics such as Physics: to be trolled by folks that don't understand what's written. :-P

Answer (score 6):

Kenneth Wilson. He won a Nobel prize for it.

Comment: Maybe you could expand this into something less snappy and more informative? :-)

Comment: I think the upvotes to this answer serve a very bad example. (even though they're probably motivated by a notorious history of the OP)

Comment: Just to clarify, there are two users with the same first name. I kind of like this answer, snappy and all, but it wasn't mine.

Comment: K. Wilson justifies renormalizations and does not do any reformulation. His lattice is similar to the old idea of W. Heisenberg about the "fundamental length" in the frame of the standard theory. It is not what I am speaking of.

Answer (score 2):

What about the [Twistor uprising](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/01/twistor-minirevolution-goes-on.html) of Arkani Hamed discussed in Lumos' blog?

> Nima explains that the goal is to think different - to eliminate the word "Feynman" from the QFT calculations as completely as possible. ;-) In particular, the new description and calculational methods proudly make locality in the ordinary spacetime obscure while they succeed in making many other, more exotic properties of the N=4 gauge theory manifest

I do not know what twistors do to renormalization, quite out of my depth. But the claim in the lecture is that they simplify QCD calculations, which is one of your worries.

Comment: I think eliminating Feynman is different from eliminating infinities. As well, if something is made manifest within _the_ _same_ theory, it is not a reformulation.

Comment: @Vladimir did you listen to the lecture? It is a completely different way of calculating.

Comment: I started listening but quit. No variable change can change physics implemented in the original equations.

Comment: @Vladimir  Strange answer.  You are asking for a change of physics? I thought that your problem was use of the renormalization technique, reformulation of QFT.  Mathematically infinities may disappear with changes of variables after all ( appear too).

Comment: Yes, a reformulation means a better physics implemented in the equations. "Success of renormalizations" signifies that this physics is close, not so far from us. You are right, with a bad variable change one can worsen convergence of the perturbative series but I believe that the original QFT equations are based on a wrong physics. This wrongness is removed with "repairing" the original solutions. There must be a direct way (a shortcut) to the final (good) results. I wonder if there is anybody who proceeds from this understanding in his activity?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone working on non-perturbative QFT really. (temporary) infinities arise from our mathematical approach.

Comment: Anyone? Are you sure? *Someone*, perhaps...

Comment: I do not ask why there are infinities in the standard QFT. I think the standard QFT has no physical exact (non-perturbative) solutions. One needs reformulated QFT to have something reasonable exactly and perturbatively.

Comment: @Vladimir: There are known exact, non-perturbative solutions to QFT's in D < 4.  Many of the known problems with renormalization really are problems with perturbation theory, anyway.  Beyond that, if someone can make something mathematically rigorous and precise that makes unambiguous physical predictions then what is your problem?

Comment: Jerry, I do not want discussions here. You closed my question.

Comment: yes, but totally no-perturbative QFT will be hard to construct and solve, so I think of partially taking into account some (essential) part of interaction and considering the rest with the perturbation theory. In other words, I think a better (more physical) initial approximation can resolve the problem of infinities in the perturbative series. The closer the initial approximation to the exact solution, the smaller perturbative corrections.